# RX 570 NITRO has damaged contact

Tags: video

The last gold contact of my card is damaged as its shown in the picture. The card was working perfectly till I saw that the fans stopped working. I sent it to sapphire cause it was still in warranty. Their answer was that it was a physical damage and it couldn't be replaced. So can I fix the problem by my self or should I throw it away.

[image: image of PCIe Card edge connector with damage]

Comment: toss it.............

Comment: Unless you have some significant soldering skills, no, you cannot fix it yourself.  If the OEM could not solve it, they could they have the machinery, that should tell you something

Answer (score 0):

Scrape it down and try it.  They won't fix any physical damage whether it's easy or not because of policy. If you are lucky it is just because the pin in the port isn't touching the card because of the raised wafer.